# Error 42P01 postgresql - express

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, typescript, express

estoy realizando un proyecto en express y desde hace unos días me salta el error 42P01 al querer hacer consultas desde mi servidor, el error solo ocurre desde ahi ya que si hago la consulta desde la terminal de postgres todo funciona bien.

Descripción de las tablas:
[image: postgres screen]

```
List of relations
 Schema |      Name      | Type  |  Owner   
--------+----------------+-------+----------
 public | users          | table | postgres
 public | usersprivilege | table | postgres
```

Pantallazo del error en express:

```
error: relation "usersprivilege" does not exist
[1]     at Connection.parseE (/home/murdoc98/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:604:13)
[1]     at Connection.parseMessage (/home/murdoc98/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:403:19)
[1]     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/murdoc98/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:123:22)
[1]     at Socket.emit (events.js:305:20)
[1]     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:341:12)
[1]     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:316:11)
[1]     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:250:10)
[1]     at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
[1]   name: 'error',
[1]   length: 113,
[1]   severity: 'ERROR',
[1]   code: '42P01',
[1]   detail: undefined,
[1]   hint: undefined,
[1]   position: '13',
[1]   internalPosition: undefined,
[1]   internalQuery: undefined,
[1]   where: undefined,
[1]   schema: undefined,
[1]   table: undefined,
[1]   column: undefined,
[1]   dataType: undefined,
[1]   constraint: undefined,
[1]   file: 'parse_relation.c',
[1]   line: '1191',
[1]   routine: 'parserOpenTable'
[1] }
```

Los codigos son para las consultas son realizados con el modulo pg, uno de ellos es el siguiente:

```
async save():Promise<QueryResult>{
        const query:string = `insert into usersprivilege (name, description) values ('${this.name}', '${this.description}')`;
        const response : QueryResult = await pool.query(query);
        return response;
}
```

Gracias de antemano :)

Comment: Lo que compartiste como imagen se comparte como texto, que desde el móvil es harto difícil leerlo y ayudar.

Comment: Ahora bien, el error habla de la tabla usersprivilege y el código que compartes refiere a users

Comment: Acabo de corregir la publicación.